# What is the safest way to store user secrets in a .NET Core application?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, app-secret, docker-secrets

While reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?tabs=visual-studio), I saw a red warning messages for both approaches: environment variables and user secrets. So what is the safest approach? And what is safest (and most practical hopefully) approach when using docker?

Comment: Can't comment on .NET best practice but as for docker. [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#examples) let you store sensitive data and access at container runtime. Prior to this ENVs or mounted files at runtime were the most common approach.

Comment: On the back of what @stacksonstacks is saying, User Secrets is only meant for local development. This is why it should only ever be included in the pipeline (in your Startup class) when `env.IsDevelopment` is true.